# Calculating Total Enum Values Java

Tags: java, arraylist, enums, playing-cards

I am constructing a card game. I have a class named Card which contains enum classes of rank and suit.

Rank contains TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6) etc.

I also have a class named Hand which contains an arraylist of type Card. I need to be able to store the total values of the cards within the hand. E.g. a hand which contains the 3 of Clubs and 5 of Diamonds and Ace of Hearts would need to equal 19 (3+5+11).

How do I go about writing this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose:

```
enum Card {
        TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6);

        private final int value;

        private Card(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
}
```

In java 8:

```
List<Card> cards = ....;
cards.stream().mapToInt(Card::getValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Give your enum a `public int getValue()` method that returns the value held by the `int value` property (or whatever name you give this property).
- In the Hand class's `getValueSum()` (or whatever you call this method), iterate through your hand's `ArrayList<Card>`, summing the values by calling this method.